# Ionic/Angular edit form content not showing

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on an edit form using Ionic/Angular with a Parse backend, and trying to have the current values displayed. My goal is if you change the text and save it, the changes will be made on the database. However, my problem is I can get the first column content to show but the second is not. The two columns of content for each row include "content" and "markup". How can I get both fields to show the default value properly?

Below is my view (edit-todo.html)

```
<ion-content>
<div>
    <ion-list>
        <li class="item item-input item-stacked-label">
            <textarea type="text" name="content" rows="10" ng-model="todo.content" required></textarea>
            <input type="text" name="markup" ng-model="todo.markup" ng-init="todo.markup" required> 

        </li>
        <ion-button class="button button-block button-positive" ng-click="edit()">
            Update
        </ion-button>
    </ion-list>
</div>
 </ion-content>
```

Also a brief snippet from the controller.js file

```
.controller('TodoEditController',['$scope','Todo','$state','$stateParams',function($scope,Todo,$state,$stateParams){

$scope.todo= {id:$stateParams.id,content:$stateParams.content,markup:$stateParams.markup};

$scope.edit=function(){
    Todo.edit($scope.todo.id,{content:$scope.todo.content, markup:$scope.todo.markup}).success(function(data){
        $state.go('todos');
    });
}

}]);
```

Comment: can you make a codepen for it ?

Comment: When you say it doesn't show, do you mean it's hidden? or not showing the correct value?

Comment: @amrhady it's not showing the second value from the database which I designated as markup. It is showing the first value (content).

Comment: Asking the obvious, but have you debugged the values inside "$stateParams" when your controller starts? And what does your URL look like?

Comment: @JeffreyTeruel, why do you use 'ng-init="todo.markup" ' in the second input? It seems you are not assigning any values to it, using ng-init.